# ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL when installing sentry-cli

Tags: node.js, sentry

I have an app running on docker container with nodejs 12.3.1
Now I'm trying to upgrade the nodejs to 16.14.2
I can run the app in local system, but when trying to deploy to docker. I get error while installing sentry-cli. Below is the error when sentry-cli is also upgraded to 2.9.0. Initially sentry-cli was at 1.57.0 (had the same error)

> error code 1
> 09:47:43  5329 error path /usr/app/src/node_modules/@sentry/cli
> 09:47:43  5330 error command failed
> 09:47:43  5331 error command sh -c node ./scripts/install.js
> 09:47:43  5332 error [sentry-cli] Downloading from https://downloads.sentry-cdn.com/sentry-cli/2.9.0/sentry-cli-Linux-x86_64
> 09:47:43  5332 error [sentry-cli] Using proxy URL: http://pkg.proxy.prod.jp.local:10080/
> 09:47:43  5332 error Error: Unable to download sentry-cli binary from https://downloads.sentry-cdn.com/sentry-cli/2.9.0/sentry-cli-Linux-x86_64.
> 09:47:43  5332 error Error message: Protocol "https:" not supported. Expected "http:"
> 09:47:43  5332 error Error code: ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL
> 09:47:43  5333 verbose exit 1

Answer (score 0):

Your proxy server (pkg.proxy.prod.jp.local) is using `http` protocol, so it cannot proxy an `https` request that our install script is performing.
Either change proxy URL or don't use it at all.
Optionally you can change the CDN address with `SENTRYCLI_CDNURL=https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cli/releases/download/`

Answer (score 0):

In China, add to .npmrc :
`sentrycli_cdnurl=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/sentry-cli`